# How to use mysql group by query

Tags: mysql, group-by, status

I have a table with columns Name, EmailId, Process, Status like below.

```
**Input**

   Name       EmailId                Process      Status    
   apple1     apple@fruits.com       process1     Closed
   apple2     apple@fruits.com       process2     In Progress
   apple3     apple@fruits.com       process3     Complete      
   orange1    orange@fruits.com      process1     Closed
   orange2    orange@fruits.com      process2     Closed
   oran       orange@fruits.com      process3     Closed
   mango1     mango@fruits.com       process1     To Start
```

Now what I would like to have is the emailId and Status of people whose Status are closed for all the Process - Process1, process2, process 3

```
**Output**

EmailId              Status    
orange@fruits.com    Closed
```

Since all the process for orange have been closed I have the above row
Similarly I would like to have all the email ids of the table whose process are closed.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
SELECT 
    EmailId
FROM
    tableX AS t
GROUP BY 
    EmailId
HAVING
    COUNT( CASE WHEN Status <> 'Closed'
             THEN 1 
           END
         ) = 0 ;
```

or:

```
SELECT 
    t.EmailId
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT EmailId
      FROM tableX 
    ) AS t
  LEFT JOIN
    tableX AS tt
      ON  tt.EmailId = t.EmailId
      AND tt.Status <> 'Closed'
WHERE
    tt.EmailId IS NULL ;
```

Comment: Thumbs Up It Worked Thank You So Much

Comment: Michael's query should work, too. Unless you have variable number of proccesses per email (and not constant 3 as the question implies).

Comment: @ypercube Michael query is not returning any recordset

Answer (score 3):

To find this, you can use an aggregate `COUNT()` to find that the count = 3 in a `HAVING` clause, hence all three are closed:

```
SELECT
  EmailId,
  /* How many different processes are closed per EmailId */
  COUNT(DISTINCT Process) AS numclosed
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE Status = 'Closed'
GROUP BY EmailId
/* Return only those with 3 processes closed */
HAVING numclosed = 3
```

If the number of possible processes isn't exactly 3 and you need to account for all of them, I believe you can use a subquery in the `HAVING` clause to find the actual number of possible processes

```
SELECT
  EmailId,
  COUNT(DISTINCT Process) AS numclosed
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE Status = 'Closed'
GROUP BY EmailId
/* Compare the number closed for this EmailId against the number of possible Process values in the table */
HAVING numclosed = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Process) FROM yourtable)
```

Comment: @aprilleocean So what _does_ it return if not what you're asking for?

Comment: If you are looking to return the status as well, there is no need because it is known to be `Closed`.

Comment: count might not work if the process in list vary, like if he wants to check if proc1, proc2, proc4 are closed, but some id has proc1, proc2, proc3 closed.

Comment: @NaveenKumar The OP specifically asks for _closed for all the Process_,

Comment: @aprilleocean Copy either example exactly as above but run it without the HAVING clause. It should return a row for apple and orange.  With the HAVING clause should return only orange.